# Search for something in a HTML-String via Python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a HTML-String with the following content:

```
          <div class="icon-box">
    <div class="result"></div>
    <div class="count">#1244587 - 16</div>
  </div>
```

This pattern is repeated hundreds of times only with, logically, other numbers. The first/left numbers have always the same amount of digits and the second/right ones have one or two digits.

Now i need the two numbers separately in a tabel. Each in a separate column. I tried to do this with re.search / re.findall but i have problems with the '<' and '#'.

Answer (score 0):

I use split() to search strings like that. Isolate that third line then

```
thirdline.split(">")[1]
```

to get "#1244587 - 16 ..." then since you know that the left numbers will always have 7 digits, you can take that string and do string[1:7] to get the left number. Then do

```
string[11:len(string)].split("<")
```

to get rid of that last "<". You can then convert them to floats and append them to a list to make a table out of them.